# Conditional rendering in streamlit

Tags: streamlit

I have a form where I need to use some conditional rendering. Basically, the form needs to change dynamically based on what the user input is. For instance, if I ask "Where did you hear about us?" and give the users some default options (e.g. "Linkedin", "Our website"..), I want that if the user selects "Other" a st.text_input appears where the user can type the answer to the question.

The problem I am facing is that:

- If I use st.form (with the st.submit_form_button), what happens is that the form does not dynamically adapt to the user's input. So the text_field won't show up at all when the user ticks "Other" in the example above.
- If I do not use st.form, then the form reloads every time the user clicks on any widget. This does not affect the functionality of the form, but it does make for a *very* bad user experience!

Any tips on how I could either include conditional rendering within st.form or just avoid the bad user experience of the form being reloaded every time the user clicks on any widget?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a sample code that we can improve upon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using form, you can create the form manually and create several containers to separate the code.

```
import streamlit as st

########################################################
# Sidebar section
########################################################
sb = st.sidebar # defining the sidebar

sb.markdown("️ **Navigation**")
page_names = [" Home", "⚙️ Other"]
page = sb.radio("", page_names, index=0)

if page == " Home":

    st.subheader("Example home")

    st.subheader("What is Lorem Ipsum? ?")
    lorem_ipsum = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry"\
                        "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book"
    st.markdown(lorem_ipsum, unsafe_allow_html=True)

else:

    other_title = '<h3 style="margin-bottom:0; padding: 0.5rem 0px 1rem;">⚙️ Other</h3>'
    st.markdown(other_title, unsafe_allow_html=True)

    lorem_ipsum = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry"\
                        "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book"
    st.markdown(lorem_ipsum, unsafe_allow_html=True)

    container_selection = st.container()
    col1_cs, col2_cs = container_selection.columns([1, 2])

    with col1_cs:

        slider_val = st.slider("Form slider")
        see_text = st.checkbox("See text")

        if see_text:
            st.warning("**See text** will take more time. Are you sure ?")

        other =  st.checkbox("Other")

        if other:
            st.info("Other checkbox")

        result = st.button(label="other buttom")


    with col2_cs:

        st.caption("&nbsp;")

    if result:

        ccp = st.container()

        with ccp:

            information_title = '<h3 style="margin-bottom:0; padding: 0.5rem 0px 1rem;"> Ipsum is simply dummy text </h3>'
            st.markdown(information_title, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]